# Disable some checkboxes in checkboxlist + FormHelper

Tags: cakephp-2.1

I am rendering checkbox list; say 10 checkboxes using the following code:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('User.hobbies', array('options' => $hobbies_array, 'multiple' => 'checkbox'));?>
```

Now I want to disable some of those checkboxes before rendering the view. Means I do not want to use the javascript to disable some checkbox. Please suggest, is there any kind of option there by which we can provide the array of checkbox values to disable some of those checkboxes. Please suggest.

Comment: There is not any kind of option yet.but we can make a helper to achieve this feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no any kind of `FormHelper` method available yet which can take two arrays, one for checkboxlist and another one for disabling some of those checkboxes. You will have to make your own Helper class extended by the `FormHelper` class.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this actually works as I haven't got the time to check it out right now, but it seems that you can accomplish this whit [FromHelper::inputs()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper::inputs). I suggest you try something like this:

```
$form->inputs(array(
        'name' => array('label' => 'custom label'),
        'hobbies' => array(
            'label' => 'custom label',
            'type' => 'checkbox',
            'multiple' => true,
            'options' => $options

     )
));
```

Where $options is an array of checkbox names with options:

```
$options = array(
   'Thing1' => array(
      'Value 1' => 'Label 1',
      'disabled' => true
   ),
   'Thing2' => array(
      'Value 2' => 'Label 3'
   )
);
```

I will also research this when I have the time, because the concept is very interesting
to know. I do not know when will I have the time to do a bit of research, but I will post a comment or update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my code is already generating a check-box list. But i only want to disable some of those check-boxes from server side. I do not want to use Jquery etc. I hope to get an answer from you.

Comment: The interesting thing here is how to disable the checkboxes server-side, that is why I used the `'disabled' => true` parameter. Try this out just for info and give us some feedback. As I said I do not have the time to test this, but it is in the TODO list.

Comment: The above code did not worked for me. May be I am missing something. My question bottom line is I want to pass an array of disabled checkbox ids those are some from the whole checkbox ids. I hope you are getting the situation. If you need more clarification, then you are welcome to ask. Thanks